# Integrate two WordPress plugins

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am looking to integrate two wordpress plugins. I have Bookly already installed and working.

I need another plugin to display the following

- percentage of work completed by an employee over X period.
- display profit and loss depending on what options are selected during the booking process.

Thank you

Reviewed applications from within wordpress